# Cannot update my website from 7.60 to any higher version

Tags: 7, media

My website is currently running on the agov-7.x-3.x-dev core and the 7.60 drupal core version. I tried to update the site to Drupal core 7.61, but site showed a fatal error.

> Fatal error: Class 'MediaReadOnlyStreamWrapper' not found in
>   /home/####/public_html/dev.####/sites/all/modules/media_oembed/includes/MediaOEmbedStreamWrapper.inc on line 12

I uninstalled the *media_oembed* module and tried again to update the site to Drupal core 7.61; another fatal error is now displayed and still the site is unusable.

> Fatal error: Class 'Class entity' not found in
>   /home/####/public_html/dev.####/sites/all/modules/fb_autopost/includes/...
>   on line 138

So I uninstalled the *fb_autopost* module and all its dependencies, and tried again to update the website to the Drupal core 7.61, but also another module displayed a fatal error and the website became unusable at all.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function libraries_load() in
>   /home/#####/public_html/dev.#####/sites/all/modules/colorbox/colorbox.module on line 224

I have tried the solution listed on the ([Registry Rebuild Module)](https://www.drupal.org/project/registry_rebuild) page hoping it will help but with no avail:

#### How To Use Registry Rebuild Without Drush

> This isn't a module, but it's just packaged as a module download to
>   make it so it's easy to find and people can download it as a package.

I cannot update my website at all. Can anybody help?

Note that all contributed modules are up-to-date; before any Drupal core update, the website used to work just fine.

Comment: You may encounter incompatibility issue replacing Drupal core from a distribution. aGov distribution needs to be updated, first. 

Try to open a support request for  to aGov distribution.

Comment: It is a critical issue of agov distribution, please see issue https://www.drupal.org/project/agov/issues/3022209